# What should I do to use Ubuntu One with different languages on different computers?

Tags: ubuntu-one, language-support

I use the Ubuntu One synchronization on different computers, where some are set in English and others set in French. Therefore, I would have liked the 'Music' folder on the English-localized computer have the same content as the 'Musique' folder on the French-localized machine.

What would you suggest me to do to achieve that? Notice that as far as the 'Documents' folder is concerned, I don't encounter this problem, since the word is the same in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do this, and the folders will have the same name in both devices.

One partial workaround could be to create a "Musique" symlink pointing at "Music" in the french-localized machine, and then you would have both "Music" and "Musique" there.

Comment: Yes I had thought a little about that, but the drawback is indeed that I get duplicates of nearly all my folders.